# tcl string map exact values

Tags: string, hex, tcl

I have a converted hex string which I'm wanting to replace.

```
Hello %user and %user2
```

I am wanting to replace %user and %user2 with the populated variable result in this case, Willma and Fred.

Where I use the tags %user and %user2 which both represent the same hexadecimal values they both get replaced with "Willma" How can I do an **exact** replace on a set of hexadecimal characters?

The code I am using:

```
set example "48656c6c6f20257573657220616e6420257573657232" ;# Hello %user and %user2 converted to hex
set modify [list "2575736572" "Willma"] ;#replace the tagSymbol as defined from the single entry %user1 | %user2
set hexData [string map $modify $example] ;#preform the swap
```

**%user** is **2575736572** in hex. 
**32** being the hex value for number 2. The next hex string becomes **257573657232**

However when I preform the string map, it swaps **%user2** leaving **32** as per design. However this isn't what I want. Below is what I am looking for.

The final output:

```
48656c6c6f20Willma20616e6420Willma32
```

when I would like it to be

```
48656c6c6f20Willma20616e6420257573657232
```

How would I do a exact swap?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of substitutions in the map of `string map` matters. In particular, at each character position it does the *first* transform in the map, and then doesn't apply any further transforms at that point. This means that `%user2` gets masked by `%user` unless it goes first. (In general, if you want to figure out an automatic order, just sort all the from-values by length, longest first. *Tcl doesn't do this for you.* In most cases where `string map` is used, either the masking effect is irrelevant or sorting at the source code level is viable.)

```
set example "48656c6c6f20257573657220616e6420257573657232"
set modify {}
lappend modify [binary encode hex "%user2"] "Fred"
lappend modify [binary encode hex "%user"] "Willma"
set hexData [string map $modify $example]
# ==> 48656c6c6f20Willma20616e6420Fred
```

Note that I used `binary encode hex` there. That's a feature of Tcl 8.6; if you're using an older Tcl, you need this little helper procedure instead:

```
proc HexOf {str} {
    binary scan $str H* hexdigits
    return $hexdigits
}
```

Comment: Absolutely marvelous. Thank you. this clears up a lot of workarounds.